# Continuous functions that are differentiable in only one point

Tags: real-analysis

Quite recently I discussed with a colleague of mine the following question: Is there a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that differentiable in one point only?

The answer is positive and the example is simple to construct: Let
$$ \varphi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \quad \varphi(x) = \begin{cases} 1, &\quad \text{if } x \in \mathbb Q, \\ 0, &\quad \text{if } x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q, \end{cases}$$ be the Dirichlet function. Then the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \ f(x) = x^2 \varphi(x)$ is only differentiable at $0$ since
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \varphi(h)}{h} = 0.$$
Moreover, it is easy to see that $f$ is discontinuous on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, so that $f$ is not differentiable there.

But this is a good point which naturally leads to the following question: "Is there a **continuous function** $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which is differentiable at only differentiable in $0$?"

I think if such a function exists, it would be given by some cleverly choosen series at $0$. I thought quite some time about the question but I still do not know the answer.

Comment: Can't you just take your favourite continuous nowhere differentiable function $g$ and set $f(x) = x^2 g(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

A much more general result was given by Zahorski:

- Zygmunt Zahorski, *Sur l'ensemble des points de non-dérivabilité d'une fonction continue*, Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France, Volume 74  (1946), p. 147-178 ([link](http://archive.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1946__74__147_0.pdf))

It says that for a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to be the set of points where a continuous function is non-differentiable, it is necessary and sufficient that it be a union of a $G_{\delta\sigma}$ of Lebesgue measure zero and a $G_\delta$ set.