# A continuous function being differentiable in a unique point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Does there exist a continuous function defined on an open interval and being differentiable in a unique point?

I have found examples of real-valued functions which are differentiable in a unique point of their sources, but all of them are not continuous at the points where they are not differentiable. I would like to know if there are examples of these kind of functions in the continuous case.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3899584/42969

Answer (score 4):

Take some continuous-everywhere nowhere-differentiable function $f$ (e.g. the Weierstraß function), and consider the function $g(x) = (x - r)f(x)$ for some real number $r$.

Then $g$ is continuous-everywhere and differentiable only at $x = r$, as required.